# Answer validation on DNN Dynamic Forms

Tags: forms, dynamic, dotnetnuke

How can I set the validation on a quiz I am developing using DNN Dynamic Forms? I want the end user not to be able to submit the quiz (ie. see the submit link), until all quiz questions have been answered correctly. Or, he/she submit the quiz but then receive submit not success due to the following questions incorrect? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more detail about your form? 1. Which asp.net control you are using to bind question/answers on your form? 2. Is there all questions in one form OR do you have NEXT/PREVIOUS buttons on your form to navigation? 3. Your answers are in multiple choices?

Comment: 1. I am not sure about this one, 2. All on one form, 3. Yes

Comment: Okay take a look in reference link (http://www.dotnetspider.com/projects/610-web-based-online-quiz.aspx). You will get some idea. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks Dexterity. I kinda figured it out by validating on the client side javascript file, which is customizable on Dynamic forms.